# Debug the admin grids and forms

Tags: magento2, grid, adminform

In Magento2 the admin grids and forms are built as I can see with a mix of require js and knockout js. Now the forms and grids are built via the `ui_component` xml files as well but because a lot of the work is done, or at least appears to be done, via js standard debugging tools like xdebug will not work.

So my question is this. What is the best way to debug the Magento 2 admin grids and forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a lot of code has been moved from the server language (PHP) to the client language (JavaScript) then you can just use JavaScript debugger instead of PHP debugger.
For example, the [Chrome browser debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) is not less powerful than XDebug.